# Button widget to datagrid in GWT

Tags: gwt, datagrid, widget

I am new to GWT. I have implemented datagrid successfully. Now I want to add a Button/Checkbox widget to the datagrid. I have gone through many sites but couldn't find the exact solution.
Hopefully I get the solution hear.

Answer (score 4):

One doesn't add *widgets* to *cell*-based widgets.

For buttons you have several choices:

- [`ActionCell`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ActionCell.html), with a fixed message and using a *delegate* to react to clicks
- [`ButtonCell`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ButtonCell.html), whose text can vary for each row (uses the `Column`'s `getValue`) and using `FieldUpdater` to communicate clicks
- [`TextButtonCell`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/TextButtonCell.html), similar to `ButtonCell` but uses the [*appearance pattern*](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CellBackedWIdgets#Appearance_Pattern) (also used by Sencha GXT btw) so you can customize the rendering (default appearance is a native button)

For checkboxes, use the [`CheckboxCell`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/CheckboxCell.html). Depending on whether you're using it to edit a boolean value or to select the rows, you'll use one constructor or the other, and possibly [a *selection event manager*](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/DefaultSelectionEventManager.html#createCheckboxManager%28%29).

You'll find examples of use in the Showcase app:

- [Cell Sampler](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler) shows you buttons (not the `TextButtonCell` though) and how to edit a boolean value with a checkbox.
- [Cell Table](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable) and [Data Grid](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid) show how to use a checkbox to control selection.

Comment: Thanks Thomas Broyer for the response,can u suggest me a sample code for adding button to datagrid

Comment: @srivani I take it that you didn't look at the Showcase? (click on "source code" above demos, choose file from dropdown list)